# Array [] operator returns a reference, so how can you change its value?

Tags: c++, arrays

As I read here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/array/operator[]/

it appears that saying `a[2]` would return the memory address (a reference) of the second element of `a`.

So how is

```
a[2]=5
```

a valid assignment, as that would mean I change the memory address of `a[2]` to location 5 (that might be possible, but usually you want to change the value, not the address) . Unless the `=` operator knows how to deal with this situation.

I know that it *doesn't* change the memory address, so what's actually going on here?

Comment: References are not addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between a reference and a pointer is that a reference is dereferenced automagically. Hence you don't need such things as `*(a[2]) = 5`.

The following code shows this:

```
int baseVar = 42;            // This
int &sameVar = baseVar;      //   and this are the same memory
                             //   with two different names.
int *pBaseVar = &baseVar;    // This is separate memory that happens
                             //   to point to the baseVar memory.
```

Changing either of `sameVar` or `*pBaseVar` will change `baseVar` itself. Changing `pBasevar` itself will *not* affect `basevar`, it will simply cause to former to point to a different location.

Under the covers (though this is, of course, implementation dependent, `basevar` is probably considered (by the compiler/code) to be the `int` at a specific address (let's say `0x12345678`), `sameVar` is considered that, too.

`pBaseVar` is considered a pointer at (for example) `0x11112222` which happens to contain the *value* `0x12345678`:

```
                      +------------+
pBaseVar (0x11112222) | 0x12345678 |--+
                      +------------+  |
   +----------------------------------+
   |
   V                  +----+
baseVar (0x12345678)  | 42 |
sameVar (same)        |    |
                      +----+
```

Comment: So as I understand it, two references can be two different names for the same value, while a pointer is a reference to a memory address (in your case the same memory address)

Comment: @PatronBernard a pointer holds a value, which is a memory address. You can change this value, i.e. make it point to a different memory address. You cannot do that with a reference. It always refers to the same object.

Comment: @PatronBernard: juanchopanza is confusing you with a syntactic purism. A pointer and reference are physically identical: within the CPU they're both just the memory address. But syntactically -- within the language -- a pointer's "value" is the memory address itself, and a reference's "value" is the dereferenced thing pointed at by the memory address. Either can be converted into the other, however, using `&` or `*`.

Comment: @Boann A reference is semantically significantly different to a pointer to warrant my previous statement. You cannot re-bind a reference like you can a pointer. It is not only a syntactic matter.

Answer (score 3):

A reference is not a memory address. Think of it as a different name for the same object:

```
int i = 42;
int& j = i; // j is another name for i

j = 55;

std::cout << i << "\n"; // i now has value 55
```

So `a[2]` can be seen as a different name for whatever object is stored at a certain location in the array. Hence, the assignemnt works as in the example above.

Comment: But from the same site (the pointer article) it says: "The address that locates a variable within memory is what we call a reference to that variable."

Comment: Oh okay, well it's explained in a confusing way then because I've read that article at least 5 times in the past year.

Comment: @PatronBernard I agree, it is confusing. Also, "reference" sometimes means "C++ reference", others times it is more general, i.e. a pointer could be said to refer to something.

Comment: @juanchopanza - `&` is the reference operator, not the dereference operator. `*` is the dereference operator.

Comment: @PatronBernard -  Note that this particular use of "reference" and "dereference" comes from C, which doesn't have references. Confusing? Perhaps. That cplusplus.com article adds to the confusion. Yet another reason not to like cplusplus.com.

Comment: Any comments on the downvote? I am happy to fix or clarify this post if necessary.